# Is there a way to monitor a github multiple repository in org using prometheus and grafana?

Tags: github, github-actions, prometheus, grafana, cicd

We are trying to monitor our github action CI/CD logs including all github commits, PR and MR request, commit history, github repository and Organization info for multiple projects using prometheus and grafana tools. We did some research but not found any valid way to integrate github action with prometheus and grafana. Is there a way to monitor a github multiple repository in org using prometheus and grafana?

Comment: I'm not aware of some ready made integration of this sort. Best guess - you'll need to write custom exporter, that will access your GitHub repositories meta data through API and then expose it as metrics for Prometheus.